# Extract text with xPath

Tags: xpath

I have a problem in xPath.

I do this:

```
//tbody/tr[td]*[2]/span/@onmouseover
```

**result:**

```
showMsgBox('Monster')
showMsgBox('Limber')
showMsgBox('Carson')
showMsgBox('Maniac')
```

I need **text**, Can I extract different texts?. I'm using scraper in Chrome. Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean you need text? you want the string inside the parentheses?

Comment: If so, that wouldnt be reachable by XPath and will need to be parsed/extracted using something else.

Comment: I think you need to do a Regexp match on your result to extract the "text".

Comment: I think do regex, I create a CSV, and I will import the data into php. thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you have an HTML structure like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span onmouseover="showMsgBox('Monster')"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And you're trying to get `Monster` out of it.

*Since you didn't share your HTML, I took a quick stab at reproducing something akin to it. It's meant to be illustrative, not exactly match yours.*

You cannot do this with just XPath. XPath allows you to select nodes in the DOM. The lowest level you can reach with XPath in this HTML is exactly what you already have:

```
//tbody/tr[td]*[2]/span/@onmouseover
```

Which returns

```
showMsgBox('Monster')
```

If you want to extract `Monster` from that you'll have to use a different mechanism, such as simple string manipulation or a regular expression.

### String manipulation

```
var text = "showMsgBox('Monster')";
text = text.substring( "showMsgBox('".length );
text = text.substring(0, text.length - "')".length);
```

Or if you don't mind magic constants:

```
var text = "showMsgBox('Monster')";
text = text.substring(12);
text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
```

Or in a single operation using `slice`:

```
text.slice(12, -2)
```

### Regular expression

You could also use a regular expression to extract the text, but I don't feel that would make things much better here.

```
var text = "showMsgBox('Monster')";
new RegExp("showMsgBox\\('(.*)'\\)").exec(text)[1]
```

or

```
/showMsgBox\('(.*)'\)/.exec(text)[1]
```