# Store image title in selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-ide

I want to store the text that appears in an image when I put the mouse over it. The image is in a table on this page https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Dragons+of+Tarkir and the first image has the following xpath `//div[@id='siteContents']/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table.1.3`. The html code of that element of the table contains the following:

```
<span onmouseover="showMsgBox('Dragons of Tarkir')"></span>
```

I want to store the content of showMsgBox. It seems that I need to know a bit of Javascript to drive Selenium IDE. What I've found so far is a [question about how to extract text with xPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406032/extract-text-with-xpath) and here is [how the Javascript function slice works](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/azg64NGdpPE). Then I think it should be something like:

```
storeText  |  //div[@id='siteContents']/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/span/@onmouseover  |  exp
storeEval  |  exp = exp.slice(12, -2);  |  expansion
```

But it throws me an error that doesn't tell too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I captured the attribute and than used substring to parse it out the value.

```
<tr>
<td>storeAttribute</td>
<td>//html/body/section/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/img@onmouseover</td>
<td>fullval</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${fullval}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>str=&quot;${fullval}&quot;; str.substring(12, str.length-2)</td>
<td>final</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${final}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Note that I used the length of the string - 2 for the "stopping" point.

Or, since these images have an ALT tag that contains the value just use that:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//html/body/section/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/img@alt</td>
    <td>fullval</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${fullval}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I just noticed an even easier way in this, jsut grab the "alt" attribute. I'll edit my answer for both.